# Add style to PagerTabStrip of Viewpager in Android

Tags: android, styles, android-viewpager

I'm working with Android ViewPager in three views. I added a android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip to display the title of each view.

**Current appearance**
[image]

**Desired appearance**

[image]

How I can get this result?

Regards!

Comment: I want to do a similar thing but I guess I'll just use Jake Wharton's library `Android-ViewPagerIndicator` in the end. Did you find any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

I customize my PagerTabStrip by customizing AppThemes in the styles.xml, the code below is how I do it in my apps.

```
<style name="_AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/mActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style> 

<style name="ActionBarTextStyle" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FF8800</item>
        <item name="android:drawablePadding">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
    </style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_example</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">10dp</item>
</style>


<style name="mActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#FF8800</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>
<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
</style>
```

Hope it helps you. =)

Comment: Could you show some PagerTabStrip code in your answer? When I add these styles they have no affect on my pager strip.